# Tagging files in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, permissions

I'm trying to edit the tags using the native Windows 8 details panel, but it seems like I cannot edit the tags, or any details for that matter. I tried clicking on the tag category in Properties -> Details but it doesn't actually open up the box to type in. Same goes for star ratings, subject, comments, title, etc.

Is this feature disabled in Windows 8? Is it for some reason locked out on my copy? Do I need some special permission to edit the details menu?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this and report back here if the problem is solved: http://betanews.com/2014/01/14/microsoft-investigating-windows-8-1s-metadata-and-tagging-problem/